# R Twitter Mining: Finding Frequency of Mentions/Hastags

Tags: r, twitter, hashtag, mining, mention

I'm very new with R. I'm using it mostly for marketing purposes so the TwitteR package is very useful.

What I'm trying to do is find the frequency of @mentions and #hashtags within my data after I've got all the data through the searchTwitter command.
I'm not sure what type of vector it turns it into right away and if I need to convert it into a data.frame or another type of vector or a corpus or what

How do I break the data down into total number of mentions/hashtags and what the frequency of each @mention or #hashtag is?

This will give me a good idea of who the key influencers and key hashtags in a specific market are and how valueable those influencers/hashtags are.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Show us your efforts

Comment: tweets <- twListToDF(tweets)
tweets <- unique(tweets)
d <- as.data.frame(table(tweets$screenName))
d <- d[order(d$Freq, decreasing=T), ]
names(d) <- c("User","Tweets")

now when I look at:
tweets$text

I see all the tweets organized in the data frame.

But now I want to separate all the mentions from the tweets and do what I did above to see how many mentions are within the tweets themselves.